# class variables and multithreading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a class:

```
Public Class GenericReturnUploadController
```

that has the following class variable:

```
Private _configSettings As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

In the method: ProcessFile, I populate this dictionary and as its a class variable it is then used by other methods called from ProcessFile including GetReportDate

```
    Public Overrides Function ProcessFile(ByVal record As Record) As Result
 LayoutRenderer.SetCurrentState(UploadServiceState.ProcessingFile, record)


            Dim code As String = record.Code

            'First get all config settings for this Return Type
            Dim dataAccess As New GenericDataAccess
            _configSettings = dataAccess.GetConfigSettings(code)

            Dim reportingDate As DateTime = GetReportingDate(record)
```

In another class: I call ProcessRecord in a Parallel.ForEach loop. This ProcessRecord then creates a new instance of GenericReturnUploadController and calls ProcessFile method.

```
Dim controller As New GenericSystemUploadController()
If recordList.Any()
    Parallel.ForEach(recordList, Sub(record) controller.ProcessRecord(record))
    recordList = controller.GetAllQueuedRecords(QueueProcessorConfigSection.GetConfig().QueueType)
End If
```

Now for my question, the _configSettings will change for each code. From what I've read, but I've not been able to verify it yet with my testing, but using this class variable could leave it open to the contents changing by other threads.. Is my understanding correct? If I change this to a local variable and then pass ByVal to other methods, will this fix any potential issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit confusing since in your example _configSettings is both a class variable and a local variable. It also depends on the instance of your class, does each thread how it's own instance or do they share it.

Comment: Thanks @the_lotus for getting back to me. I've updated the code sample to use the class variable (I was trying out things when I created this post) and to provide more detail. Worth noting is that an instance of the controller is created before the Parallel.ForEach loop. This loop calls ProcessRecord() which in turn news up GenericSystemUploadController class which has the class variable that I'm concerned about.

Comment: If _configSettings changes for each value of code, then perhaps a different variable type for it is needed.

Comment: If each record have a different config and record is a parameter, then _configSettings should be a local variable. If you have two threads running the same function, the config will be mixed.

Comment: Hallelujah! A well asked question ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I removed the use of class variables (I had a few more and initial testing is good )